# What does ${!variable:0:1} mean in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I've been reading a script and come across a point where it goes beyond my understanding. The snippet from the code is below:

```
while getopts ":h-:" OPTION; do
        case "$OPTION" in
         -)
                case "$OPTARG" in
                   time)  
                        if [ ! -z "${!OPTIND:0:1}" -a ! "${!OPTIND:0:1}" = "-" ]; then
                        Time="${!OPTIND}"
                        OPTIND=$(( $OPTIND + 1 ))
                        fi ;;
                 esac
                ;;
        h)      Usage 0;;

# More code

       esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))
```

The point where I'm struggling with is the `if` condition. What does it actually mean?

I know about the `getopts` and the relevant variable `OPTIND` and `OPTARG` it provides, but quite struggling to find out what condition is being fulfilled by the `if` statement.

If anyone can explain that to me, it would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's suppose you have these vars:

```
foo=bar
bar=0123456789
```

Code

```
echo ${!foo}
0123456789
```

will give you the value of `$bar`! This called indirect expansion. And this code:

```
echo ${bar:0:3}
012
```

will return first 3 symbols of `$bar` This is like slices in python.
Now let's combine these commands:

```
echo ${!foo:0:3}
012
```

We get first 3 symbols of `$bar`

Comment: Addendum - if the variable is an array (standard or associative), the behavior of the `!` changes to mean "show me the indexes." `ray=( a b c ); echo ${!ray[@]}` outputs `0 1 2`.